# pass html input checkbox to controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, html, inputcheckboxes, boolean

i try to get the value from `<input type="checkbox">`and pass it to my variable on controller but i always get **'Argument cannot be null'**. i already try using inputHidden to `<select>` tag and `<input type="text">` and it works but why it didn't work on `<input type="checkbox">`.

Did i do it correctly ? i do it based on [Get text input value with the help of HTML and pass it to controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88431/get-text-input-value-with-the-help-of-html-and-pass-it-to-controller) answer

--Visualforce--

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!CC}" id="ccId"/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.ccId}').value = this.value;" />Kartu Kredit</label>
```

--Apex Class--

```
public Boolean CC{get;set;}
public PageReference Submit(){
   web2lead.Credit_Card__c =CC;
   update web2lead;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.checked` instead `this.value`

We know in case of checked box, we need to check checked attribute not value.

if it a `input type="text"` then we need to use value

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!CC}" id="ccId"/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.ccId}').value = this.checked;" />Kartu Kredit</label>
```

Class

```
public Boolean CC{get;set;}
public PageReference Submit(){
   web2lead.Credit_Card__c =CC;
   update web2lead;
}
```